# MariaDB Overloaded UDF

Tags: mariadb, user-defined-functions

I have a requirement to create a function that can accept any data type and return a value of any data type, that being said, the data types are limited to, DateTime, Timestamp, Varchar, Int, Decimal :)

For instance:

`SELECT foo(a, b)`

The data types of a and b are unknown and the return value is also unknown at the time of function definition. Is there a way/workaround to this problem?

Originally I was thinking of defining the function multiple time with different data types as input and as output, MariaDB won't let me create it a second time with different data type arguments :)

I have done a lot of research before posting this question, most likely it's not possible but just trying my luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings (`VARCHAR`) work in almost all situations.